# Validation responses in REST API

Tags: json, rest, error-handling

I'm designing a RESTful API and wondering what's the best format for validation error messages.

For example, my account creation endpoint accepts a JSON object:

```
user: {
  first_name: string,
  last_name: string,
  address: {
    street: string,
    city: string,
    zip_code: string
  }
}
```

My responses will be in the following format:

```
{
    code: 400,  // HTTP code
    message: "Validation failed",  // general message
    type: "validation_failed",  // there are other types of errors as well
    errors: WHAT_DO_I_SHOW_HERE
}
```

I have several choices for validation error messages:

Format 1

```
errors: {
  last_name: "First name is required",
  address: {
    zip_code: "ZIP code is invalid"
  }
}
```

or flatten the errors as in Format 2

```
errors: {
  last_name: "First name is required",
  "address.city": "City is required",
  "address.zip_code": "ZIP code is invalid"
}
```

or use an array, where each element can have field name, error code, error message, nested errors, etc.

```
errors: [
  {
    field: "first_name",
    message: "First name is required",
  },
  {
    field: "address",
    errors: [
      {
        field: "zip_code",
        message: "ZIP code is invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

or

```
errors: [
  {
    field: "first_name",
    message: "First name is required",
  },
  {
    field: "address.zip_code",
    message: "ZIP code is invalid"
  }
]
```

Apparently the array format is more flexible since field name is optional, so it can accommodate errors related to a combination of multiple fields (e.g., end time of a time interval must be after the begin time). But my question is, which one would be easier for API users to consume?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer having an errors response as an **array** to an object. An error array can represent multiple errors per one field.

```
errors: [
    {
        field: "name",
        message: "name should be at least 4 characters"
    },
    {
        field: "name",
        message: "name should not begin with a dollar sign ($)"
    },
    {
        // other fields
    }
]
```

For a nested field, I would represent it as array of string.

```
errors: [
  {
    field: ["address", "zip_code"],
    message: "ZIP code is invalid"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me working in front end html, I would prefer to flatten error format 2. It will be easy for me to look into it, or easy to target an error to display.

Open to listen others opinion

Answer (score 0):

So your clients would have to check the HTTP Status Code, and if it's not 200 OK, they'd have to look into errors and deserialize that JSON into the model object? What happens if there's a different kind of error (say a BadRequest, a Conflict, or a DB-related error, for example)?

Why not return a generic

```
errors: [
  {
    type: "ValidationError", // or an int value from an Enum
    message: "First name is required",
  },
  {
    type: "DBError",
    message: "Connection not found" // you might want to say something more generic here, but at the same time if you don't treat it at all it will bubble up as a 500 internal server error
  }
]
```

Now of course both might not happen at the same time, but still, you want your API as generic as possible, to spare your clients from bundling up "if"s in their code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a bit outdated, but JSON API Specification says

> Error objects MUST be returned as an array keyed by errors in the top level of a JSON API document.

[Here is a link](http://jsonapi.org/format/#error-objects)